# Unity Animations

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change character animations using a script, based on key inputs, but Unity seems to only play the default "standing idle" animation and occasionally switching to the "crouched idle", is there a different way to handle animations or am I just doing the script wrong? Here is my script as it currently stands

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterControl : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animator animator;
    public bool crouched;
    private string sc;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (crouched == true) {
            sc = "crouch";
        } else {
            sc = "standing";
        }

        animator.Play (sc + "_idle");

        if (Input.GetButton ("Fire3")) {
            if (crouched == false) {
                crouched = true;
            } else {
                crouched = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```c#
if (Input.GetButton ("Fire3")) {
    if (crouched == false) {
        crouched = true;
    } else {
        crouched = false; 
    }
}
```

with

```c#
if (Input.GetButton ("Fire3")) {
    crouched = true;
} else {
    crouched = false;
}
```

Now, when you hold down the "Fire3" button, your character should crouch, and when you release it he/she should stand again

Also a suggestion: Put the other code in the function (`if (crouched == true) ... animator.Play (sc + "idle");` after this code (the `Input.GetButton` check). That way, your character should instantly start crouching the same frame that the button is pressed; otherwise, he/she will the frame after

---

### Explanation

`Input.GetButton` will return true while you're pressing down (in the middle of clicking or touching) on the button *each frame*. Each time `Update` is called (around 1/60th of a second) your code will check if you're pressing down, and toggle `crouched`. When you click/tap the button, you'll likely be pressing down for a few frames, so `crouched` will switch from `true` to `false`, back and forth, a few times. In some cases (when you press down for an odd number of frames) `crouched` will be switched, but in other cases (when you press down for an even number of frames) `crouched` will stay as it was before you clicked on the button, preventing your character from crouching, or standing if he was crouching before.

Source: From the official API: [`Input.GetButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html)

Comment: I like the idea, but I am trying to make crouch a toggle action as opposed to having to hold the button down. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Previously my code had Input.GetButtonUp in place of Input.GetButton, but I neglected to change that back when I posted my code

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using animation states and transit from one to another when you get an input. Checkout my answer at: [Unity 2D animation running partially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529542/unity-2d-animation-running-partially/38621854#38621854)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the toggle action like this

```
void Update()
{
   if(Input.MouseButtonDown(2))
  {
    crouched = true;
  }
  if(Input.MouseButtonUp(2))
  {
    crouched  = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: My apologies for the late comment, but im not having a problem with registering change in state, i was actually looking for how to switch the animations and not have it revert to default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
crouched = Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3") ? true : false;
```